# Why are the flat paper objects in my scene disappearing in and out again?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Help! I made a corkboard type of scene and the papers are cutting in and out for some reason. And no, It has nothing to do with the clip start and end settings, or the papers being too close to the board. I moved them a TON and nothing changed.

[image: This is the poster board with the problem. I added a ton of pictures to it and half of them keep disappearing when I rotate the view.]

[image: Another picture but from a different viewpoint. (THAT'S THE ONLY DIFFERENCE and they disappear)]

[Here is a video of the problem](https://youtu.be/foO1ShIvmdU)

Comment: Are the papers absolutely flat against the wall? What I mean is, are they in the exact same spot as the wall? If the papers and the wall behind them occupy the same space, the camera cannot decide what's supposed to be "in front" at any given time and will waver between which it displays (possibly based on camera angle). If this is the case, move the papers "forward" even as much as .0001 of a unit.

Comment: please upload your blend file, if Christopher's answer doesn't help you.

Comment: so this was the first thing I thought of, christopher. I moved them around and they are not very close to the wall. its so wierd. I'll upload the file.

Comment: heres the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PPUi2SBUv3zbEhSTrG2hy9E_KzvdA6iT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem is only visible in eevee render viewport mode.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.